# How to make the background reset to blank each time, and how to make it so that if I click a key, the code responds

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I'm in the process of creating a Stroop Test on a website called Trinket.io and I need to know how to make the background white after each word is displayed, and how to display a "Correct" or an "Incorrect" after clicking a corresponding key. I couldn't figure out how to make the code look like code and I do apologize for this.

I haven't tried much, as I really have no clue where to start, but what I have tried was to put the bgcolor(white) into the loop such that it should turn white after every event, which didn't work. I tried to find a way to clear the screen during each cycle as well but could find nothing.

```
from turtle import Turtle, turtle, Screen
import random
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
tina = turtle.Turtle()
tina.hideturtle()
tina.speed(0)
colors = ['black','blue','yellow','green','red']
texts = ['Black','Blue','Yellow','Green','Red']
NoOfTrials = 0
while NoOfTrials <= 100:
  Start = str(raw_input("Press X to begin the test! "))
  color = random.choice(colors)
  text = random.choice(texts)
  if Start == 'x' or 'X':
    tina.color(color);style = ('Arial', 100, 'bold');tina.write(text, font=style, align='center')
    screen.bgcolor('white')
```

Alright so this code, when you run it, it will ask you to write an x, then you click enter and it will then give you a random word in a random color. Ideally, you click the key on the keyboard corresponding to the words' color (Stroop Test), and then it says "Correct" or "Incorrect" and then clears the screen and gives you a new word and color. It is eventually supposed to measure the time it took you to press the button and then give the average results in the end but I don't know how to code that so it isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Use turtle.clear() or turtle.clearscreen() to clear everything on the screen.

```
...
if Start == 'x' or 'X':
    tina.clear()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

My belief is you're not going to get where you desire given the direction you're heading.  This can't be programmed with a simple loop -- since turtle keyboard clicks are events, your code can't simply stop wait for them to happen.  What might work for you is a *state machine* that turns on and off events based one what should happen next and then lets the event system take over.  For example:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop
from random import choice

NUMBER_OF_TRIALS = 10

COLORS = {'b': 'Blue', 'g': 'Green', 'r': 'Red'}

LARGE_FONT_SIZE = 100
LARGE_FONT = ('Arial', LARGE_FONT_SIZE, 'bold')
SMALL_FONT = ('Arial', 24, 'bold')

color = None
score = 0
trial = 0

def do_nothing():
    pass

def change_text():
    global color, trial

    screen.onkey(do_nothing, 'space')  # disable spacebar
    turtle.clear()  # erase "Press spacebar ..." text

    trial += 1

    color = choice(list(COLORS.values()))
    turtle.color(color)

    text = color
    while text == color:  # make sure color and text don't match
        text = choice(list(COLORS.values()))

    turtle.write(text, align='center', font=LARGE_FONT)

    for character in COLORS:  # (re)enable keyboard keys that correspond to colors
        screen.onkey(lambda c=character: selected(c), character)

    screen.ontimer(get_ready, 3000)  # user has 3 seconds to identify color

def get_ready():
    for character in COLORS:  # disable keyboard keys that correspond to colors
        screen.onkey(do_nothing, character)

    turtle.clear()  # erase last word shown

    if trial == NUMBER_OF_TRIALS:
        turtle.write("Final score: " + str(score) + " out of " + str(NUMBER_OF_TRIALS), align='center', font=SMALL_FONT)
        return

    screen.onkey(change_text, 'space')  # (re)enable spacebar

    turtle.color('white')
    turtle.write("Press spacebar to continue.", align='center', font=SMALL_FONT)

def selected(key):
    global score

    for character in COLORS:  # disable keyboard keys that correspond to colors
        screen.onkey(do_nothing, character)

    if COLORS[key] == color:
        score += 1  # a match!

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.listen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-LARGE_FONT_SIZE/2)  # adjust center position for font height

get_ready()

mainloop()
```

If running in standard Python turtle, make sure you click on the window to get started as the spacebar and 'r', 'g' and 'b' inputs are to the turtle window, not the console.